# Should we edit closed questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

In the last day, I've noticed a few edits on questions that have been closed for a rather long time ([example 1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20753/all-portal-2-achievements-and-how-to-get-them), [example 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24985/done-with-portal-12-what-other-similar-game-can-i-play)).  While some closed questions can be simply reworded or rephrased to become on-topic and reopenable, the questions I've seen seem like they will never fall into that category.

By editing these questions, we bump off-topic questions back to the front page, wasting space for questions that are actually good questions.  Is there a reason I'm missing for why we should be editing these questions?

**Edit**
So now that we can [reject suggested edits for custom reasons](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2333139#2333139), is something along the lines of @Raven's "Do not disturb the dead" a reasonable response?

Comment: I'm partial to a new Suggested Edit Reject reason: "Do not disturb the dead!"

Comment: Related question: what criteria do we use to delete closed questions?  If a question has been closed because it has never been, is not now, and cannot be made into an on-topic question, deleting it would solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Obviously, [at least 16 people + waffles think so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92614/152101).  Enough to change the system to allow it.  That said, those questions *don't fit*.  The one question I actually suggest an edit on after it was closed was because everyone NARQ-ed it and I think I understood what he was trying to say, so I clarified.  Your first example *does* seem unnecessary, but the second was just a tag edit.  We can live without tag edits on a closed question, but if it's going to exist, it may as well be searchable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see no reason to be editing either of the two examples given. The first example is partially my fault since I approved the edit thinking that the "question" was an answer that had been posted. However, given the rather unorthodox way that the question was written, I don't think I'm entirely to blame for this. The second example is adding the game-rec tag back into a question, which is bad, since the game-rec tag should be killed entirely by now along with all game-rec questions.

Basically, if a closed question isn't being reworded or rephrased to become on-topic or reopenable, or unless you're removing a tag that shouldn't exist on the site anymore(for example, removing the[game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) tag as I am now) I don't think there's any reason to edit it.

Comment: *I don't think I'm entirely to blame for this.*       
I think you are. You monster.

Comment: One thing to consider is if you're just editing to remove a tag and there is no chance of a question being reopened (such as a game rec or a similarly off-topic kind of thing), you might as well just delete the question instead of retagging it.

Comment: @AnnaLear I hadn't considered that somehow! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you think you can salvage a question, I say go for it. As for the two examples, the first one is a statement, and the second isn't salvageable at all.